# TreeView class in WPF class

Tags: c#, tree, wpf, winforms

We are converting a WinForms application to WPF. so I need to accept the input like WinForms. As I don't want to change the logic of it. Ao I write the class for those its works. But the is not good please take a look at the class once and suggest the edits in this class.

```
 public class TreeItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private TreeItem()
        {
            if (Nodes == null)
                Nodes = new TreeItems();
        }
        private TreeItem(string DisplayName, string IdName) : this()
        {
            this.DisplayName = DisplayName;
            this.IdName = IdName;
        }
        public TreeItem(string DisplayName, string IdName, TreeItem parent = null) : this(DisplayName, IdName)
        {
            Parent = parent;
        }

        bool isChecked = false;
        private string idName = string.Empty;
        string name = string.Empty;
        private object tag;

        public object Tag
        {
            get { return tag; }
            set { tag = value; }
        }

        public bool IsChecked
        {
            get
            {
                return isChecked;
            }
            set
            {
                isChecked = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("IsChecked");
            }
        }
        public string IdName
        {
            get
            {
                return idName;
            }
            set
            {
                idName = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("IdName");
            }
        }
        public string DisplayName
        {
            get
            {
                return name;
            }
            set
            {
                name = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Name");
            }
        }

        public TreeItem Parent { get; set; }
        private TreeItems nodes;
        public TreeItems Nodes
        {
            get
            {
                return nodes;
            }
            set
            {
                nodes = value;
                foreach (var item in nodes)
                {
                    item.Parent = this;
                }
            }
        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(propertyName))
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
    public class TreeItems : IList<TreeItem>
    {
        public TreeItem this[string itemName]
        {
            get
            {
                return GetNode(allParents, itemName);
            }
        }
        public TreeItem GetNode(List<TreeItem> currentList, string name)
        {
            foreach (var item in currentList)
            {
                if (item.IdName == name)
                {
                    return item;
                }
            }

            foreach (var item in currentList)
            {
                TreeItem treeItem = GetNode(item.Nodes.allParents, name);
                if (treeItem != null)
                {
                    return treeItem;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
        List<TreeItem> allParents = new List<TreeItem>();
        public TreeItem this[int index] { get => throw new NotImplementedException(); set => throw new NotImplementedException(); }

        public int Count => throw new NotImplementedException();

        public bool IsReadOnly => throw new NotImplementedException();

        public void Add(TreeItem item)
        {
            allParents.Add(item);
        }
        public void GetParent() { }
        public void Clear()
        {
            allParents.Clear();
        }

        public bool Contains(TreeItem item)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void CopyTo(TreeItem[] array, int arrayIndex)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public int IndexOf(TreeItem item)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void Insert(int index, TreeItem item)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public bool Remove(TreeItem item)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void RemoveAt(int index)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public IEnumerator<TreeItem> GetEnumerator()
        {
            return allParents.GetEnumerator();
        }

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return GetEnumerator();
        }
    }
```

the way im assigning the parent is bad. so any ideas will be helpful thanks.

Usage:

```
TreeItems  tvLieferantsItems ;
tvLieferantsItems[betr["PARTID"].ToString()]?.Nodes[betr["BETID"]?.ToString()]?.Nodes[betr["BERID"].ToString()]?.Nodes.Add(abt);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Review

- I see no reason to have 3 constructors, each invoking the other, when two of them are private and only called by another constructor. Keep it simple.
- You check for  `if (Nodes == null)` in the constructor. Is there a scenario where this reference could have already been created upfront?
- Constructor arguments should be camel cased.
- There is no point in initializing `idName` and `name` because they get overwritten by the constructor chain.
- Call `OnPropertyChanged` with `nameof(IsChecked)` rather than `"IsChecked"`. Or perhaps with a lambda `OnPropertyChanged(x => x.IsChecked)`. This avoids nasty typo's and is more robust against future changes.
- Property `Nodes` has a public setter. Check the value against null, and navigational integrity (nodes can not be descendants, ancestors, self or children of a different parent).
- Property `Parent` should not have a public setter. Private would do fine here. This way, you avoid consumers messing with the navigational integrity of the tree.
- `PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, args)` is a cleaner way of invoking the event.
- Method `GetNode` does not use any instance state or behavior, so it should be made *static*.
- Method `GetParent` is void, which is uncommon for a method named `Get*`. Its method body is also empty, which is even more uncommon :) What is the purpose of this method?
- Method `Add` is public and accepts a parameter. I bet the parameter is not allwoed to be null. Check it against null and throw an appropriate exception.
- Finish the implementation of the class. Don't throw `NotImplementedException` for methods you should definitely implement.

Comment: thanks for that and  public TreeItems Nodes
        {
            get
            {
                return nodes;
            }
            set
            {
                nodes = value;
                foreach (var item in nodes)
                {
                    item.Parent = this;
                }
            }
        }// how can i change this part of the implementation